# Using Webtest 2017 Why does my Form Post Parameters flip after I checkout the code from the repository?

Tags: forms, visual-studio, webtest

Using: Webtest 2017
Note:  I'm a webtest newbie

I recorded a few steps on a webpage and on one of the pages I am selecting a file I want to upload.  In the Webtest script I have a Form Post Parameters folder with two parameters.  One being license and the other being File Upload Parameter.  When I record the request using Fiddler the request is FileUpload first and license last.  Webtest for some reason has license then FileUpload.  If I run the test with license then Fileupload the script fails.  So I manually cut and paste to have Fileupload and then license, the test will pass.  However when I check in my code and then check out the code, the code has license first and Fileupload second so the script will fail.

I'd like to share the script but I am not allowed.  So I added the lines below.
[image: The File Upload step needs to be first.]

Is there a setting I don't have turned on that causes these two files to switch?  It could be something simple, but I don't know.  I tried to separate the request and have 1 being the fileupload and the second being license, but that wont work.  Sorry again that this is a high level description.  Let me know if there's anything else I can add to this message to help explain the issue I'm having.

Note:  I took a look at the XML and it seems to be setup correctly.

```
 <FormPostHttpBody>
            <FileUploadParameter 
 Name="DataSource1.Upload_Submit_App#csv.UploadApp" FileName={{DataSource1.Upload_Submit_App#csv.UploadApp}}" ContentType="application/x- 
zip-compressed" GenerateUniqueName="False" UseGuids="False" FileUploadName=" 
{{DataSource1.Upload_Submit_App#csv.UploadApp}}" HtmlEncodeFileName="True" 
 />

 <FormPostParameter Name="license" Value="{&quot;licenseType&quot;:&quot;Free&quot;,&quot;basePrice&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;IsPerDeviceLicense&quot;:false,&quot;trialType&quot;:&quot;TimeBased&quot;,&quot;trialDays&quot;:30,&quot;trialCredits&quot;:100,&quot;usageUnit&quot;:&quot;&quot;}" RecordedValue="{&quot;licenseType&quot;:&quot;Free&quot;,&quot;basePrice&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;IsPerDeviceLicense&quot;:false,&quot;trialType&quot;:&quot;TimeBased&quot;,&quot;trialDays&quot;:30,&quot;trialCredits&quot;:100,&quot;usageUnit&quot;:&quot;&quot;}" CorrelationBinding="" UrlEncode="True" />
          </FormPostHttpBody>
```

Comment: Is it the checkin+checkout that is altering the order? If yes then this is not a webtest issue. If no then please [edit] the question to explain the problem more clearly.

Comment: It was a checkin+checkout issue, not an issue with the webtest.  At that time I did not know what was causing the issue.  Is there a way for me to change the Title of this post?

Comment: Yes. Click the [edit] link just under the question's body.